# Create React App - console lint warnings don't match eslintrc

Tags: reactjs, eslint, create-react-app

I've got a sort of weird problem, that I don't see any mention of elsewhere.

Create React App by default seems to log lint warning in the terminal when running `yarn start` and also in the Chrome console. All good. Makes sense, and I've seen discussions of whether this functionality should exist, and how it should work.

My issue is that those warnings seem not to match my `.eslintrc` settings at all!

As in, if I run `yarn lint`, which runs `eslint` using my settings, I see none of the warnings that show up in the console and terminal when I start my app.

For example, I have this rule turned off in my `.eslintrc` file:

```
"radix": 0,
```

And, consequently, there's no `radix` warning when I run `yarn lint`.

(Just in response to the answer below. I've tried a variety of options for this particular rule, including "as-needed". But I wanted to turn the rule off entirely, which I've evidently accomplished, because running `yarn lint` shows no errors related to `radix` at all).

But when I start the app, I see this in yellow warning boxes in the console:

[image]

Anybody know why my `.eslintrc` file is being ignored here, and how to get these warnings to represent the rules I've set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/radix#options), you should pass either `"always"` or `"as-needed"`. The latter should disable those warnings.

```
...
"radix": "as-needed",
...
```

EDIT: According to this [source](https://alligator.io/react/linting-react/#customizing-create-react-app-and-eslint), you will have to eject your `create-react-app` to edit the ESLint settings.

Comment: Thanks -- I used to have that, and it was showing the same problems. As needed only shows the warning where necessary -- I wanted to turn the rule off entirely. And indeed, it appears to work when I run `yarn lint`, so I don't think that can be the problem

Comment: It appears that `"as-needed"` should make it so you only have to use radix parameters when they are not base 10. Could you share the code that is producing the linting error?

Comment: Actually, according to this [source](https://alligator.io/react/linting-react/#customizing-create-react-app-and-eslint):   "One drawback with the defaults in a project created using Create React App is that you can only configure ESLint by `ejecting the project`".

Comment: Bingo. How annoying. I'll just continue to ignore them then. Thanks!

Comment: You could disable those warnings with a comment before the lines where you use `parseInt()` -> `// eslint-disable-next-line`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add `EXTEND_ESLINT` flag to the .env file.

When set to true, ESLint configs that extend eslint-config-react-app will be used by eslint-loader. Any rules that are set to "error" will stop the application from building.

Source: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration

Your eslint config may be named `.eslintrc.json` and put in the root folder of your project.
Its contents should look like the following (note the extends field):

```
{
  "extends": "react-app", //this extends statement is required
  "rules": {
    "radix": "as-needed"
  }
}
```

And the `.env` file placed in the root should have the following line:

```
EXTEND_ESLINT=true
```